# Closing out html tags in ReactJS

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm learning Reactjs and am wondering about JSX parsing. It looks like I'm getting the error "Unterminated JSX Comments" because I'm not closing out each open tag within it's respective class. Is this true? And if so, what would be an elegant way of correctly placing my <html></html> tag in a modular way? I'd prefer not to place it directly in App.

```
class App extends Component {
   render() {
     return (
      <div className="App">
         <Header/>
         <Body/>
         <Footer/>
      </div>
      );
   }
}
```

Header Class:

```
class Header extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <html> {/* <!-- HTML tag is OPENED --> */}
        <head>
          <title>
            Data Uploader
          </title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <div class="content">
              <div class="nav blue">
                  <div class="logo">
                    <img SRC="./images/logo.png"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="title">
                    Data Uploader
                  </div>
                  {/* End of nav */}
              </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Body Class: {Use your imagination. Some content goes here}

Footer Class:

```
class Footer extends Component{
  render(){
    return(              
          <div class="footer">
          <div class="footer_text">Data Uploader | Copyright 2017 | Developed by Me</div>
          {/* <End of footer */}
          </div>
          {/* End of content */}
        </div>
    </body>
    {/* <!-- HTML (and body) tag is CLOSED--> */}
</html>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't your client-side ReactJS application being loaded within an opened/closed `<html>` and `<body>` in index.html (or equivalent) already? Can't `Header` be element wrapped in `<header></header>`, `Footer` wrapped in `<footer></footer>`, `Body` in `<main></main>` or equivalent semantic HTML5 tags? ReactJS component are supposed to be isolated/encapsulated elements ideally.

Comment: Alexander, you're absolutely correct. My question seems so stupid now. This would also mean that I don't have direct control over the title or head tags within my App class unless I modify the default React template found in index.html. Makes sense. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: It's definitely not stupid, all our applications are structured differently with different needs and challenges :). There are libraries such as [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) and others that help generate `<head>` tags such as `<title>` and `<meta>`. Definitely worth checking out if you need control over that section of the DOM from within ReactJS components.